# Why does my program not accept a custom exception?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to make a `cat` clone and I'm up to requiring it to receive input when presented with a `-`.

The main(); is here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class cat {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

      try{
       filePrint(args[i]);

        }   catch(DashException letsTryThis){
           catDash();
        }   catch(FileNotFoundException wrong) {
           System.err.println(String.format("%s: File Not Found.", args[i]));
        }   catch (IOException noWords) {
           System.err.println(String.format("%s: File can't be read.", args[i]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`filePrint()` just prints the file line by line and `catDash()`receives and prints stdin. Nothing special.

What I'm trying to do is have a custom exception that specifically catches a `-` and calls `catDash()`(first catch block above). However, no matter what, the try/catch block always throws the `FileNotFound wrong` exception (second catch block above). My question is, how do I get it to catch a specific cause and throw it first before the second block does?

My `DashException` as defined it its own file:

```
import java.lang.Throwable;

public class DashException extends FileNotFoundException{
  public DashException(Throwable cause){
    super("-")
  }
}
```

Comment: DashException is a FileNotFoundException... why don't you just throw a FileNotFoundException???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not throw your custom exception from anywhere. You need to `throw` it in your own code in the `try` block. E.g.:

```
if (args[i].equals("-")) {
     throw new DashException();
}
```

And you can remove the `th` from the constuctor, as there is no root cause for this exception.

Comment: filePrint() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, and my custom DashException. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You don't need to add it in the signature, as `DashException` is a  `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: And just adding your exception to throws declaration wouldn't do no good for your specific exception if it doesn't throw it like @meskobalazs showed.